# Extract only IP's from text

Tags: regular-expression

```
trans(776800911)[10.173.36.75]: Request processing failed: Network Error, from URL: 10.173.36.73:57743
trans(776800912)[10.173.36.75]: Request processing failed: Network Error, from URL: 10.173.36.74:57743
trans(776800913)[10.173.36.75]: Request processing failed: Network Error, from URL: 10.173.36.75:57743
```

Comment: Just IPv4 addresses, or IPv6 too?

Comment: For each line, which IP address do you want? Or is it both? Do you want the port number too?

Comment: Finally (so far), what have you tried already? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/462585/edit) to include responses with this missing information.

Comment: 10.173.36.73 || 10.173.36.74 || 10.173.36.75 ,-- theses IP's I want to extract

Comment: The .75 IP shows up twice in line 3; are you trying to match it in a certain place in the line?

Comment: Please [EDIT YOUR QUESTION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/462585/edit) in response. Do not reply in comments because it's too easy for people to miss.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -oP '\K[0-9.]+(?=:.*)' < ips.txt
10.173.36.73
10.173.36.74
10.173.36.75
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Sorry , I forgot to mention that I am looking for splunk rex expression to get the IP's

Comment: Could you add this in your original question so that it might be helpful for others?